# Graylog Frontend Technology?

Tags: javascript, architecture, webserver, graylog

I need to inject some Javascript snippets in Graylog front end in order to inspect end user sessions, and i want to know how Graylog is architectured (technology used in the front end), or else if i can add a webserver like Apache on top of Graylog to solve this matter.

Thank you